# Using Proxies With Node App On Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, proxy, server, instagram-api

So I have a Node.js app setup on Heroku. The app works with a private Instagram API - and Instagram has some strong authentication and anti-spam systems. The Heroku server is located in Virginia, but the users of my app will come from all over the world.

When the Instagram API checks and finds these large changes in geo location between logins, it continues to throw errors asking "Is this you?" type of stuff - ultimately not allowing a connection.

I've researched and found that proxy servers may be a solution for this issue, but I'm clueless as to how I can use them with an app on Heroku. Is it possible to have a proxy mimic the location of a user's IP to pass Instagram's authentication? What is the best way to use proxies in a node.js application on Heroku? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make the Instagram requests with your server - whose location does not change?

Comment: It currently does. But, for example, since a user may be in Brazil when they log in to Instagram normally, and then my software running in the server in Virginia logs in to their account, that's what is causing the problem. That huge location change.